# Last GPS position of a out of battery/sim Android Phone

Tags: gps, android-device-manager, gps-tracking

Having no specific apps on the lost android phone (e.g. GPS tracker etc), is there a way to find out at what position the last GPS signal was sent? I use Android Device Manager and there it actually states when the last *time* the phone was online, but it does not say anything about last *position*. Note that GPS is activated on the lost device which by the way has no SIM card and no battery left.

Comment: Have you tried out the 'Find my phone' feature in Google Search ??? If not, try it out. It might be related in some way, I think.

Comment: It seems to be related to the ADM mentioned above.

Comment: I guess so, but it shows it in Maps, and Maps uses GPS to some extent.